boost::bind linker error in C++ builder 10.4
This is using the 32-bit compiler without clang enhancements and Boost 1.39 from GetIt. Even with the following simple example
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/function.hpp>

float f(float x)
{
   return x;
}

int main()
{
   float x = 5;
   boost::function<float(void)> g = boost::bind(f, x);

   return 0;
}

I get the following linker errors
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'boost::_bi::bind_t<float, float (*)(float), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<float> > > boost::bind<float, float, float>(float (*)(float), float)' referenced from ...
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unresolved external 'boost:boost::_bi::bind_t<float, float (*)(float), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<float> > > * :addressof<boost::_bi::bind_t<float, float (*)(float), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<float> > > >(boost::_bi::bind_t<float, float (*)(float), boost::_bi::list1<boost::_bi::value<float> > >&)' referenced from ...
[ilink32 Error] Error: Unable to perform link

(paths removed by me)
All the header files are there and compilation completes succesfully before linking. According to this old documentation boost::bind is suppoerted in 1.39 https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/bind/bind.html.
I am able to use other things from boost without issue (e.g. just boost::function without bind).
Thanks in advance for any help you can offer

Try to find the implementation of bind_t. Is it defined in the header file? Maybe some boost library must be linked with your app

Boost Bind is header only. This makes little sense unless you have actually split the code over translation units and they are compiled with different compiler flags/library versions.

This example compiles for me in C++ Builder 12.1.
